# numbering the rows with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, t.*
FROM some_table t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
ORDER BY t.title
```

I want to numerate the rows from the table, and also to sort it with `ORDER BY`.

When I use `ORDER BY`, the user variable `@row` isn't 1,2,3 because of the `ORDER BY`.
How can I select the rows with `ORDER BY` and have correct numbering?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 rank FROM some_table t, (SELECT @rank:=0) r order by @rank
```

or

ordering by any other field

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 rank FROM some_table t, (SELECT @rank:=0) r order by id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select @row := @row + 1 as row,t.* from (
select * from some_table,(select @row:=0) as r order by title) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to pre-return the result set RANKED, THEN assign the row number to it

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, 
       PreQuery.*
   FROM 
      ( select t.*
           from Some_Table t
           order by t.title ) PreQuery,
      (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

The only problem with doing it in this fashion is that it basically runs through the table 2 times... first to get the records in proper order, then apply them joined to the @row implementation to properly be correlated to the respective rank.